# Dockerfile with centos:latest and pdns

Tags: docker, centos, powerdns

I have a simple Dockerfile using centos:latest which fails to find pdns using yum.  This is running on Windows host.

$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d

Dockerfile_dns

```
FROM centos:latest

RUN yum update -y

RUN yum install -y epel-release pdns pdns-tools pdns-backend-postgresql pdns-backend-sqlite pdns-recursor net-tools bind-utils jq
```

Using command
$ docker build -t dns_img -f Dockerfile_dns .

```
#5 [2/3] RUN yum update -y
#5 sha256:103582845ea3b4ba6361ca1a570ed91dbb7ffbdb7bd1b67e3dc21635f2dfc8da
#5 CACHED

#6 [3/3] RUN yum install -y epel-release pdns pdns-tools pdns-backend-postgresql pdns-backend-sqlite pdns-recursor net-tools bind-utils jq
#6 sha256:6639667b2dcec34132dc4bfb88fe520d625f4ab8de649b631344017f22fbd2d7
#6 2.419 Last metadata expiration check: 0:16:22 ago on Fri Sep 24 16:21:33 2021.
#6 2.788 No match for argument: pdns
#6 2.792 No match for argument: pdns-tools
#6 2.796 No match for argument: pdns-backend-postgresql
#6 2.800 No match for argument: pdns-backend-sqlite
#6 2.804 No match for argument: pdns-recursor
#6 2.817 Error: Unable to find a match: pdns pdns-tools pdns-backend-postgresql pdns-backend-sqlite pdns-recursor
#6 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yum install -y epel-release pdns pdns-tools pdns-backend-postgresql pdns-backend-sqlite pdns-recursor net-tools bind-utils jq]: exit code: 1
```

I found some references to using a specific centos version, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you don't have those dependencies in the repositories you have installed.

install this repo and you'll have the packages you need:

```
RUN yum install epel-release
```

After you can install your packages:

```
RUN yum install -y pdns pdns-tools pdns-backend-postgresql pdns-backend-sqlite pdns-recursor net-tools bind-utils jq
```

Installing the repo and the dependencies only it holds can't be done because yum executes the installation in one take instead of one after the other like python's pip for example

Comment: It's right there on line three.
RUN yum install -y epel-release pdns pdns-tools.....

Comment: you have to do this first, that's why some tutorials split their `yum install` to multiple parts , it all happens in one go. run this before and then install everything else

Comment: @wood.wheels did it resolve your issue? if so please accept the answer

Comment: The epel-release has to be on a separate line. Change your answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant by running it first, I'll make it clearer